# JWT Bearer token expiration doesn't append JSON payload under IIS (.Net Core)

Tags: .net-core, iis, jwt, windows-server-2016

I use this code to configure JWT Authentication for my .Net Core API and the authentication works correctly. Also the token expiration management I made in the `OnChallenge` event works (returns 401), but the JSON serialization of the Error instance is append in the body of the response only under debug and not in production under IIS on Windows Server 2016.

I tried to move the expiration management under `OnAuthenticationFailed` event but nothing has changed.

Below two screenshot made with Postman under debug and production.

Any advice?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };

                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();

                    options.Events.OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
                        {
                            string message = "Invalid token.";
                            
                            if (context.AuthenticateFailure != null && context.AuthenticateFailure is SecurityTokenExpiredException)
                                message = "Session expired.";

                            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                            
                            Error error = new Error(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, message);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(error));
                        });

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });
```

Debug, localhost:

[image: Debug, localhost]

Production, published API:

[image: Production, published API]

**EDIT (01/11/2023)**: Looking the event viewer on the IIS machine, it says:

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer
EventId: 2
SpanId: f067d16734396fba
TraceId: 2755980dcc0dac70a6311f503cf5f81b
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 8000453e-0003-f800-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /api/v1/Payslips

Connection ID "17870283335901660474", Request ID "8000453e-0003-f800-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception: 
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to the response body, the response has completed.
Object name: 'HttpResponseStream'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpResponseStream.ValidateState(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpResponseStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.StreamPipeWriter.FlushAsyncInternal(Boolean writeToStream, ReadOnlyMemory`1 data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MyProject.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<<ConfigureSecurity>b__4>d.MoveNext() in C:MyProject\Program.cs:line 150
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.FireOnStarting()
```